# Creating a dropdown menu using icon in R and updating plot

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

the given plot creates the snap as below. However, after clicking on the Circle icon, I just see the first element in the dropdown, I want all the dropdown elements to appear i.e "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F". The warning I get is mentioned below the script:

```
## app.R ##
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
dashboardHeader(),
dashboardSidebar(
),
dashboardBody(

dropdownButton(
  pickerInput(inputId = "uppickerIcons", 
              label = "", 
              choices = c("A", 
                          "B", 
                          "C", 
                          "D", 
                          "E", 
                          "F"), 
              choicesOpt = list(icon = c("glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right", 
                                         "glyphicon glyphicon-cog", 
                                         "glyphicon glyphicon-play", 
                                         "glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign", 
                                         "glyphicon glyphicon-euro", 
                                         "glyphicon glyphicon-music")), 
              options = list(`icon-base` = "")),
  circle = TRUE, status = "danger", icon = icon("gear"), width = "300px",
  tooltip = tooltipOptions(title = "Click to see inputs !")
 )
 )
 )
 server <- function(input, output) 
 {
 }
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Warning Message:

```
Warning in if (!is.na(attribValue)) { :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in charToRaw(enc2utf8(text)) :
argument should be a character vector of length 1
all but the first element will be ignored
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try this dropdownbutton https://dreamrs.github.io/shinyWidgets/#dropdown-button ?

Comment: Hmm, awesome, but it solves my problem partly, the symbol in download button when clicked should give me choices with icons as asked above. I still see the standard selectInput here. I'll try to code myself but if you can help me, would greatly appreciate :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand problem right I think. An icon has to be clicked and then a drop down has to be shown with elements and icons in it. Is it? so the elements should also have icons!

Comment: Absolutely, if you see the "Plot","Summary" and "Table" with icons in that snap, and upon clicking these options, the plot besides should update. options can be in the form of a drop down

Comment: Will see, but if a quick solution is required. ```Unicode``` to rescue :) https://tutorialzine.com/2014/12/you-dont-need-icons-here-are-100-unicode-symbols-that-you-can-use

Comment: I am very grateful Sir, if you are able to resolve it, please help me.

Comment: This is what was needed, see "Update choices"                                      Link: https://dreamrs-vic.shinyapps.io/shinyWidgets/, I just have to make it reactive now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154439/discussion-between-amrrs-and-ashmin-kaul).

Comment: I have tried your approach and now, the dropdown just shows one element. Updated the script for your reference. Please check.

Comment: @amrrs, kindly help me with the current post as I am stuggling with the on-click. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47987238/overcoming-the-issue-of-na-values-without-hard-code-to-create-plotly-charts